# Methods that return a value java not working

Tags: java, class, methods

Let say I have a typical java class like

```
public class Waiter {
    private int Id;
    private String name;
    private int active;
    //Including constructor, getter and setter
}
```

And now I want to make a function that can change the variable in active. I know, in this case, I can simply use the setters, but I want to inside a function that I can call when I need to.

My function currently looks like this

```
public void login(int a) {
    int b = 2;
    a = b + a;
}
```

Now I want to call it with

```
login(2)
```

but it won't update my a value in main?

Comment: You want to make change in the value held by active but I can only see the updation being done on  value held by `a` that too which is a *local* variable

Comment: Classes can access their own private fields without getters and setters.

Comment: "_but it won't update my a value in main?_" You never updated `active` anywhere. "_I can simply use the setters, but I want to inside a function that I can call when I need to_" That's what a setter is, a method you call when you need to. Why is that not sufficient?

Comment: Can you provide us main method please.

Comment: Use Tell Don't Ask http://wiki.c2.com/?TellDontAsk

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You got the logic behind your `login(int a)` method wrong.

By calling `login(2)` you are passing the value ([call-by-value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40480/is-java-pass-by-reference-or-pass-by-value/40523#40523)) of 2 to the **local variable** `a` and then add `b` to it and it does work e.g. if you would print the value at the end:

```
public void login(int a) {
        int b = 2;
        a = b + a;
        System.out.println( a ); // this prints 4 if login(2) is called.
    }
```

To preserve this value you must either assign the new value to another variable e.g. `active = a + b;` or return the value so that the value is returned by the method and can be stored outherwise:

```
public int login(int a) {
        int b = 2;
        a = b + a;
        return a;
    }
```

This would allow you to do something like this in your main method:

```
public static void main( String[] args )
{
    Waiter wa = new Waiter();

    int stored = wa.login( 2 );
    System.out.println( stored ); // prints also 4
}
```